# Add new row to Datatable from table values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, datatables, clone

I have a Datatable with information, and a fieldset with a table full of text inputs. The user should be able to add new rows according to the information values, but these rows are not correctly adding. Clearly the tr is being cloned and added (emptied where needed),  the corresponding values are appending but the pagination is not being updated for Datatables. I cannot figure out how to correctly use .fnAddData() to get the job done here. On top of that, I don't know how to go about the "Permissions" column - getting checkboxes to convert to text for the table. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/BWCBX/28/

**jQuery**

```
$('#addRow').click(function () {
    var tbody = $('#example tbody');
    var tr = tbody.find('tr:first').clone();
    tr.find('td:first').text($(".engine").val());
    tr.find('td:eq(1)').empty();
    tr.find('td:eq(2)').empty();
    tr.find('td:eq(3)').text($(".version").val());
    tr.find('td:eq(4)').empty();
    tr.appendTo(tbody);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are good examples on how to use `fnAddData` in the [API docs](http://datatables.net/api).

I have rewritten your JS according to example provided in docs. I've extracted checkboxes checking into separate function to mantain high readability. The updated fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z85QC/1/).

Comment: thanks, this works nicely. I edited my above dilemma to use checkboxes as well. Do you know how to tackle this beast?

Comment: simply add values to checkboxes, just as you did with text inputs.

Comment: Right, but I need the text to show only if they are checked. http://jsfiddle.net/BWCBX/29/

Comment: you can use jQuery `:checked` selector, see my updated answer.

Comment: Rybak, how would I go about adding an icon next the the engine value? Rather than just $(".engine").val() add .html() as well.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Try adding a new question which will describe the problem precisely.